# Why is there so much space between <h3> and <p>

Tags: html, css

I don't get it. Why is there so much space between "title" and "text"? Please take a look at this code:

```
 <h3 style="background:#000">Title</h3>
        <p class="d" style="background:#000">
       Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
        </p>
```

There are absolutely no other styles applied to those two elements, but still, there are so much unused space. Anyone have an idea here?

[image]

Comment: Default style of your browser?

Comment: `h3` tag has default top & bottom margins. Hence the space. Learn to use Developer console in your browser to debug such issues.

Comment: Try on other browsers also and then let us know.

Comment: I've just tried in newest firefox, chrome, and IE 8. All browsers show the same as this browser ( chrome )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The caption tags (`<h1>`, `<h2>`, ...) have a default padding and margin applied to them.
The same is for the paragraph `<p>`

If you want to remove those default spacing add the following style to the captions and paragraphs inside your css or element:

```
padding: 0; margin: 0;
```

Comment: Nice answer RononDex! Also, check this useful article (about what's the default margin of headers elements): http://www.htmlcssdeveloper.com/tutorial/advanced-html-css/what-is-the-default-margin-of-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-h6.html

Answer (score 7):

try to give `margin:0 for h3 and p`

Answer (score 4):

Css Resets should usually be applied to CSS code so that your styling is only affected by what you put in, not default styling. http://www.cssreset.com/ contains some nice resets you may choose to use. This occurs as default margins set on headings are showed, a simple style of:

```
h3 {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

Would resolve for this specific element only, thus the css resets come in handy for resetting all HTML elements to be without style.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use reset.css to eliminate the default margin and padding. 
[meyerweb's reset css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) can be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `<p>` is a paragraph. And by default paragraph has `margin-top: 1em;` and `margin-bottom: 1em;`. `<h1>` - `<h6>` is a heading tags, and by default it has `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` from `2.33em` to `0.67em`